# Converting an old mcrypt_decrypt script to openssl_decrypt

Tags: php, php-openssl

I'm having trouble getting an old PHP 5.6 script using `mcrypt_decrypt` converted to `openssl_decrypt` in PHP 7.

Here's what used to work:

```
$decrypted = trim(
            mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
            substr(sha1($this->key), 0, 32),
            base64_decode($params),
            MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
            base64_decode($iv)), "\0..\32");
```

And here's what I tried:

```
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt(
            base64_decode($params), 
            'AES-256-CBC', //have tried AES-128-CBC with no luck
            substr(sha1($this->key), 0, 32), 
            OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, 
            base64_decode($iv)
        );
```

The code is actually part of a web framework, so when I `print_r` the decrypted data, I get this:

[image]

I have almost zero idea about encryption, so would appreciate some help! :-)

Comment: @SumanDey Why I'm getting garbage instead of proper decoded data. It's actually supposed to be a json-encoded array or something readable.

Comment: When you decrypt a data, it's supposed to be human readable. There is no need to do a double decrypt. Maybe you are trying to decrypt first, then encrypt with openssl.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I'm not doing a double decrypt. The first one is the old script, the next one is what I tried as replacement.

Comment: I see no reason why this wouldn't work, the parameters match perfectly - check if `$params`, `$iv` and `$this->key` match (`bin2hex()` is your friend to see the binary data); if they do - look elsewhere.